# Reference request - spectral radius formula for linear transformations in char p

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis

I am finishing up a paper and I would like to be able to quote a theorem that does what
is said in the title. To be specific let me introduce some notations:
${\bf F}$ is a local field of charateristic $p>0$, $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value on ${\bf F}$ normalized by requiring that $|\pi|=q^{-1}$ where $\pi$ is a uniformizer for the valutation ring ${\bf A}$ of ${\bf F}$. Now let  $X$ be a ${\bf F}$-vector space of finite dimension, $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $X$ having the same value group as the normalized absolute value. Given an endomorphism $T:X\rightarrow X$ let $\|T\|$ be the standard operator norm with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$. What I would like to have a reference for is the following assertion:

**Assume that $T$ has all its eigenvalue in ${\bf F}$, and denote the set of eigenvalues of $T$ by $Sp(T)$, then
$ \lim_{d\to\infty} \|T^d\|^{\frac1d}= \max_{\lambda {\in}Sp (T)} |\lambda|$**

note: I am not asking for a proof, I just would like to be able to point to some precise reference instead of asking the reader to adapt result obtain in different setting to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a reference off hand, but I don't see any harm in just claiming that the assertion easily follows from the Jordan decomposition of $T$.

After all, if you know that the limit on the left hand side exists you just write $T = D + N$ for some diagonalizable over $\mathbf{F}$ endomorphism $D$, and some nilpotent endomorphism $N$ where $D$ and $N$ commute, and observe that for large $n$,

$$||T^{p^n}||^{p^{-n}} = ||D^{p^n}||^{p^{-n}} = ||D|| = \max_{\lambda \in Sp(T)}|\lambda|.$$

You can also show in this way that the limit exists by being a bit more careful.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to the proof I had in mind, still I would like to know if there is a precise reference one can quote for this fact.